# Extrude outward

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a Quidditch scene from Harry Potter.

I want to extrude a face outward while still keeping the existing face. I can't explain well so please see my images:

[image: Extrude1]

[image: Extrude2]

I'm also not sure how to make the outer trees follow a circle. Should I use "Follow Path"?

[image: Quidd]

Thank you.

---

Blender 2.92

Windows 10

Comment: It seems like your post asks two separate, largely unrelated questions. Stack Exchange works best when you ask only one question per post—consider moving your second question into a separate post. Also, instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: As Alexis says, please give some details, if you extrude some faces I'm afraid you need to unwrap the new faces. For you second question, Array modifier with Object Offset is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: If you want to extrude a section, but keep it "filled" with a face, duplicate the face first (shift + d) then right-click so it snaps to its original position, then extrude.

Comment: @AlexisKing
Oh sorry for two question. I will do that!
Also I understood about Images,
Thank you.

Comment: @moonboots Sorry  I will ask more detail next time.
And I will try Array modifier! Thank you,

Comment: @ChristopherBennett That's I want to do! And I did !
Thank you!!

Comment: @ChristopherBennett And also I'm grateful for making better sentences.

More one thing I want to ask you, my images is more 2MB so I could not upload, but you could. How did you upload??

Comment: I'm not sure. I just downloaded it from your link and re-uploaded. The largest was 1.1Mb for me. Maybe they got compressed when you uploaded them.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Oh I see.. Anyway, thank you so much!